# Combine [quote] and [quotes] into a single tag

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retag-request

There are a few questions on MSE tagged with [quote](/questions/tagged/quote) (*10 questions*) and [quotes](/questions/tagged/quotes) (*19 questions*).

While some of these questions should be retagged with [blockquote](/questions/tagged/blockquote), a majority of these questions seem to be asking about "quotation marks".

**Any questions about markdown quotes should be retagged as [blockquote](/questions/tagged/blockquote). To prevent  future confusion, [quote](/questions/tagged/quote) and [quotes](/questions/tagged/quotes) should be combined into a single [quotation-marks](/questions/tagged/quotation-marks) tag.**

Alternatively, I would also be ok if the quote tags were burninated, as they aren't used by many questions.

Answer (score 2):

Only a few questions seemed to need [quotation-marks](/questions/tagged/quotation-marks). The rest were either retagged [blockquote](/questions/tagged/blockquote), tagged with something else more appropriate, or had the tag removed altogether.

[quote](/questions/tagged/quote) and [quotes](/questions/tagged/quotes) are now gone.